# Query about hidden turtles

Tags: netlogo

What actually happens to hidden turtle? I mean after we hide the turtle it continue to live in invisible mode occupying memory as I guess.

I hide few turtles but did not ask them to be shown back and when I inspected the hidden turtles continuing simulation their attribute were changing as per my commands. So, what exactly hiding a turtle sense for.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my simulations, turtles represent people making decisions about whether to protect themselves during an epidemic. There are tens of thousands of these turtles, with potentially hundreds on some patches. The turtles don't move, but they each make their own decision based on personal characteristics like attitude and environmental perception such as how close the epidemic is.

Having these turtles visible would just clutter up the screen. Instead, I hide them and colour the patch based on what proportion have adopted protective behaviour. This is much more informative.

In my most recent simulation, though, I make the turtles size 0 instead of hiding them. This still makes them disappear, but I can still right-click on the world view to access the list of turtles where I have clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to hide turtles is when you are simulating an infinite plane and turtles outside the view should simply be hidden.
Note that if you are moving turtles using `setxy` rather than `forward` you should test to make sure the patch you are about to move to exists since `setxy` throws a runtime error if it is given coordinates outside the world. From NetLogo documentation:

```
ifelse patch-at (new-x - xcor) (new-y - ycor) = nobody
[ hide-turtle ]
[ 
  setxy new-x new-y
  show-turtle 
]
```

Comment: Thank you. So die and hidden are different concepts if i am not wrong.

Comment: Yes totally.  A dead agent ceases to exist. The effects of this include:

1 - The agent will not execute any further code.  

2 - The agent will disappear from any agentsets it was in, reducing the size of those agentsets by one.

3 - Any variable that was storing the agent will now instead have nobody in it.
 
4 - If the dead agent was a turtle, every link connected to it also dies.

5 - If the observer was watching or following the agent, the observer's perspective resets, as if reset-perspective had been run.